# When 'dynamic-IP extension' is failed?

Tags: dynamic-ip

- What I want to know :

When my computer keeps one network method and asks for a renewal and extension of its current address lease to the same DHCP server, Can my computer fail to renew the lease?

If this can occur, When? and Why?

- My situation

I'm trying to keep a audio-streaming to a server which has a dynamic IP.

And use UDP.

So if this server fails to extend its current address, Clients will throw packets(audio-data) to somewhere strange.

Comment: Off-topic here. Personally, though, I don't think you'll have many issues with this. Normally the same computer (MAC) will get the same IP as it did the last time (lease extension will succeed) unless there's a conflict or an overall change in the network reconfiguration. My laptop has had the same IP for months at a time in large corporate networks.

Comment: Thank for your appinion. I agree with you. But I will use a computer(as server) which connected with speakers in conference hall. Because there will be many people, I need to ensure there is no issue.